# I'm getting an error when I try to upload an excel file to my RStudio server

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R Studio Server. When I try to upload a file from my desktop, I'm getting

```
Error: 'path' does not exist: 'data/sweets.xlsx'
```

This is the code I'm using to upload my file

```
sweetsimport <- readxl::read_xlsx('data/sweets.xlsx')
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Nevermind. Please do not answer this as I have worked it out

Answer (score 0):

That path is not a path to your desktop. Assuming you are on a Mac and 'data' is a folder in your desktop with 'sweets.xlsx' directly inside of it, the correct path would be `~/Desktop/data/sweets.xlsx`. Another way to get an *absolute path* on a Mac is to click a file and press option-command-c to copy the pathname.